# Can I change what disk different parts of my system are located on after installing it?

Tags: boot, partition

So I've recently installed Linux alongside Windows, but I've come to think that I maybe should uninstall Windows. Because of the limited space available on my SSD due to Windows, I put my home and swap partitions on the SSD, but the root on the HDD. I've now changed my mind and think that, with Windows out of the picture, a more sensible arrangement would be root, swap and boot on the SSD, and home on the HDD (I'm not sure about it, though).

Given this, I need a way to change where these partitions are located.
I know how to shrink, grow, and move partitions with GParted, but how do I swap partitions, move partitions between disks? How do I tell the system where the partitions are? Do they have IDs? Can they be assigned/preserved? Is there a configuration file? How can I edit it to reflect moved partitions?

Note that I believe altering the boot and swap partitions won't be necessary, in case these are more difficult to deal with.

More info:
I installed Pop!_OS 20.10 on a Lenovo Legion Y530. I don't think I have Grub on my system.

Comment: Backup anything important and reinstall

Comment: Really? There's no better way?

Comment: I would make space, copy `/home` to its new location. After that it gets tricky and I would not be able to explain. It is not very hard, if you know what you are doing. But un-likely to boot on first attempt.

Comment: One idea (from a life-boot) would be: shrink partitions, create partitions in empty spaces, use `cat` to move partitions (e.g. `cat /dev/sda1 > /dev/sdb3`), remove old partitions, expand size if new partitions and then reinstall boot loaders. Alternative: External HDD as buffer. To be honest: Backup and reinstall seems way easier; POP can use `dpgk` for a list of installed packages for reinstallation ([see here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9135/how-to-backup-settings-and-list-of-installed-packages)) - assuming that you did not play around with system settings too much, this would do fine.

Comment: Could you dump your `df -h` and state if you have an external drive that could fit all?